# Showing a rectangle over a video from camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

Basically I need to capture the video from videocamera do some processing on frames and for each frame show a rectangle of detection.

Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYd2kAN0Y20

How would you superimpose this rectangle on the output of videocamera (usb)? (c++)

Comment: Using what set of tools/APIs?

Comment: Oh, cool. I didn't know that it was OpenCV when I answered the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use OpenCV, an open source imaging library to get input from a webcam/video file.
Here is a tutorial on how to install it:

http://opensourcecollection.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/how-to-setup-opencv-22-in-codeblocks.html

Then I would use this code:

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

To get the image, `frame` from the `CvCapture`, `capture`.

In this case, `capture` is taken directly from a video camera, but you can also create it from a video file with:
`CvCapture *capture = cvCreateFileCapture("filename.avi");`

Then, I would draw on the image with functions defined here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html

By the way, the shape in the Youtube video is not a rectangle. It's a parallelogram.

---

If you want to do it live, then you can basically put this in a loop, getting a frame, processing it, drawing on it, and then outputting the image, like this:

You would include this before your loop:
`cvNamedWindow("Capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`

And then, in your loop, you would say this:
`cvShowImage("Capture", frame);`

After the processing.

---

**EDIT** To do this in C++, open your webcam like this:

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;
```

To initialize it from a file, instead of putting in the camera index, put the file path.

Get a frame from the camera like this:

```
 Mat frame;
 cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
```

Then you can find drawing functions here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_drawing_functions.html

Cheers!

Comment: but is that possible realtime like the video? there is lot of processing going on.. I would suspect that video is a fake?

Comment: Maybe it's not realtime. Maybe he just got the frames, processed them, and then put them back into a video. http://myopencv.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/creating-your-own-videos-in-opencv/